# Optimizing file reading

Tags: python, data-science

I have 2 files, where for each line of one file, I have to search through the other file to find corresponding info. The first file (category 1) contains line-separated json objects, where each object contains reviewer, item ASIN, rating and time stamp in that order (looks like this):

```
{"overall": 5.0, "verified": true, "reviewTime": "01 5, 2016", "reviewerID": "A2V0JXLJ9VCNNX", "asin": "B00570RQ0A", "reviewerName": "Amazon Customer", "reviewText": "washer washing", "summary": "Five Stars", "unixReviewTime": 1451952000}
```

The other file is the metadata which also contains line-seperated json objects, where each object contains product description, links to images, and other product info (looks like this):

```
{"category": ["Appliances", "Parts &amp; Accessories", "Refrigerator Parts &amp; Accessories"], "description": ["Little Giant ACS-2 Auxiliary Condensate Drain Pan Overflow Shut-off Switch, 48 VAC/VDC, 18\" Leads (599122)Auxiliary condensate switch installs in the condensate drain pan of an air conditioning or refrigeration unit, to turn off the unit if the drain pan approaches overflowLittle Giant ACS-2 Auxiliary Condensate Drain Pan Overflow Shut-off Switch, 48 VAC/VDC, 18\" Leads (599122) Features: ABS housing Polyethylene float 48VAC/VDC max 5 amps max Low voltage 18\" lead wiresLittle Giant ACS-2 Auxiliary Condensate Drain Pan Overflow Shut-off Switch, 48 VAC/VDC, 18\" Leads (599122) Specification: Cord Length: 18\" Shut Off: 0 Voltage: 48 VAC/DC Amps: 5 Weight: 0.21 Height: 3 Width: 1.34 Length: 4.55.", "Little Giant ACS-2 Auxiliary Condensate Drain Pan Overflow Shut-off Switch, 48 VAC/VDC, 18\" Leads (599122)Auxiliary condensate switch installs in the condensate drain pan of an air conditioning or refrigeration unit, to turn off the unit if the drain pan approaches overflowLittle Giant ACS-2 Auxiliary Condensate Drain Pan Overflow Shut-off Switch, 48 VAC/VDC, 18\" Leads (599122) Features: ABS housing Polyethylene float 48VAC/VDC max 5 amps max Low voltage 18\" lead wiresLittle Giant ACS-2 Auxiliary Condensate Drain Pan Overflow Shut-off Switch, 48 VAC/VDC, 18\" Leads (599122) Specification: Cord Length: 18\" Shut Off: 0 Voltage: 48 VAC/DC Amps: 5 Weight: 0.21 Height: 3 Width: 1.34 Length: 4.55"], "fit": "", "title": "Little Giant 599122 ACS-2 Float Switch with 18-Inch Lead, 1-Pack", "also_buy": [], "image": ["https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/413p5bagSJL._SS40_.jpg"], "tech2": "", "brand": "Little Giant", "feature": ["Little Giant", "ABS housing, polyethylene float", "72\" lead wires"], "rank": [">#128,783 in Tools &amp; Home Improvement (See top 100)", ">#2,384 in Tools &amp; Home Improvement &gt; Appliances &gt; Large Appliance Accessories &gt; Refrigerator Parts &amp; Accessories"], "also_view": ["B000JGH2TM", "B0026WSD4A", "B000SM342Q", "B003QK4KUM", "B005D4RFEM", "B00DK85P9A", "B000FK9W0E", "B013K33QQI", "B079NQ1532", "B004496WNW", "B01N19NQLN", "B000AHT78O"], "details": {}, "main_cat": "Tools &amp; Home Improvement", "similar_item": "", "date": "October 4, 2007", "price": "$19.65", "asin": "B000WQZFFW"}
```

Basically, for each item on every line of the first file, I'm searching through the metadata to retrieve price info and the product description related to that item.
Currently, I'm using a double for loop to achieve this, as shown below. Is there any way I optimize my code better?

```
def get_ecoList(category1, metaCat):
    global meta
    meta = read_metadata(metaCat)
    with open(category1, 'r+') as y:
        data = y.readlines()
        tempArr = []
        idx = 0
        for line in data:
            metaFlag = 0
            currLine = line.split(',')
            i = currLine[0]
            if i in tempArr:
                continue
            tempArr.append(i)
            items[i] = 0
            global prices
            prices[idx] = '$1.0' #change to prices[idx] = avg_prices[i]
            for k in meta:
                if 'asin' in k and k['asin'] == i:
                    metaFlag = 1
                    if 'price' in k:
                        if len(k['price']) > 0:
                            prices[idx] = k['price']
                    if 'description' in k:
                        if len(k['description']) > 1:
                            k['description'] = ''.join(k['description'])
                            ecoList.append(k['description'])
                        elif len(k['description']) == 0:
                            ecoList.append('N/A')
                        else:
                            ecoList.append(k['description'][0])
                    else:
                        ecoList.append('N/A')
                    break
            idx += 1
            if metaFlag == 0:
                ecoList.append('N/A')
    prices = [float(re.findall("\d+\.\d+",x)[0]) for x in prices if x != 0]
    y.close()
```

Comment: You don't think the content of the files is relevant to the question?

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks, I just updated the post.

Comment: Have you considered storing the files in dict ? with ASIN as keys ? so it is easy to itereate the keys from one file/dict, then find the other key in the other ? dict are fast to handle this key lookup. It depends on the size of your files ...

Comment: @Malo Sure. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: @javaMan, as you do not show a full minimal working example, it is a bit tricky. Could you make a [mre] ? here is the principle : 1 read the files and put them each in a dict. Then :

dict1 = {1: {1:1, 2:1}, 2:{1:2, 2:2}}
dict2 = {1: {3:1, 4:1}, 2:{3:2, 4:2}}

for k, v in dict1.items():
    print(k, v, dict2[k])
    # do what you want here

Comment: Seems you could easily read all that data into a pandas dataframe and merge them together.